# Delaying the loading onset of elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that is rich in content such as graphics and javascript. Now the problem is that my page loads too slow, especially with slower internet connections. Now at the bottom of my webpage I have a jquery slider, which is the least important item on my website. 
now...
Is there a way I can postpone or delay the loading of that whole slider(which has a div ID as parent element) until directly after everything else has loaded on my page, and not alongside the rest of the more important content?

Comment: Define "everything else has loaded on my page". Are you referring to *$.ready*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you might want to look up javascript loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [LABjs](http://labjs.com/).

The principle is that you inject the script-tag that loads your javascript. For instance, you could have the following code as the last element before your `</body>`-tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];        
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'url/to/script.js';
head.appendChild(newScript);
</script>
```

Comment: I assume the "head" element refers to the div containing my JS slider? So the fact that this script, calling/loading the slider is at the bottom of the code hierarchy(just above the /body tag), makes it loads at the very last? I want it to start loading only after everything else has completely finished loading

Comment: Actually, `head` refers to your html-document's head-tag. Putting this last in your body-tag ensures that your slider component is parsed last. The browser will start loading the the script as soon as the javascript is parsed, but it will problably load it asynchronously together with any remaining objects.
Is there a certain component that needs to be loaded before the slider can be initialized?

Comment: I stumbled upon an excellent article from CSS Tricks about [thinking of javascript asynchronously](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/)

Comment: Don't understand. <head></head> and <body></body> tags are kept separate from each other, head preceding body. How can I put the head tag last into my body tag? Thank you for that article you posted, really helpful!

Comment: No, I meant that you should put the script last, not the html-tag. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough!